# Error: unable to start debugging on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have designed and development my website using visual studio 2010 mvc3. I have copied my project from my server and after editing database server name I am trying to run my project. But it is showing error that:

> Unable to start debugging on the server. The debugger cannot connect to the remote computer. 
>   This may be because the remote computer does not exit or firewall may be preventing
>   communication to the remote computer. Please see help or assistance".

Please help me. Thanx in advance

Comment: You are starting a remote debug session. Is it your intention to debug at the server?

Comment: No Sir.. I just want to debug my project on my local host. Please help me

Comment: One moment, I'll need to start VS 2010, in the mean time, you can check the property pages of your project (right click project and click properties). In the `Debug` section there should be an option to select the preferred debug location.

Comment: Dear sir.. I am not able to get any debug section in project properties. I have spent whole day to resolve this issue. Please suggest me...

Comment: I was mistaken, the tab is called `Web`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tab` in question is `Web`.

Can you check if the setting mach these?:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i add this tag to my web.config

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true"></compilation>
```

you should set debug = `true`