# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The debugger cannot connect to the remote computer in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, remote-debugging

I've just started to work on a MVC project. It's a web portal. I've set my sites on my local IIS 6.0
But when I want to start debugging, I get this error:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The debugger cannot
>   connect to the remote computer. The debugger was unable to resolve the
>   specified computer name.

[image]

I don't understand that when I want to debug my project locally, what **"Remote computer"** it's talking about??!!

Please help me guys, this is my first task in this company and I have to overcome this error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23539779/4753489

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: unable to start debugging on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539371/error-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-server)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check all the steps outlined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If you're using a hosts file, make sure you have an entry for the site in question. That was the problem for me, when I encountered this message.

Comment: Thank you, your link helped me to resolve the issue. In my case, I needed to add IUSR & IIS_IUSRS to the permissions and also, I needed to modify etc/hosts file. Now, it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem.
My first solution delete url site from iis repositories and project properties write localhost and port number if is it. And debug began working without restart. I also think, may be if add new url in windows host file this can fix this trouble but may be need restat iis or visual studio.

IIS
[image: IIS]
Project properties
[image: Project properties]