# Problems in IIS and visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

I am receiving the error, `"unable to start debugging on the web server. the debugger cannot connect to the remote computer. the debugger was unable to resolve the specified computer name"` in visual studio. I have two websites already working in IIS, but can not get this third one to work.

[image]

I have tried an IIS reset and many other alternatives

Comment: I think there is a post This may help u
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684127/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-the-debugger-cannot-connect-to-the?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to start debugging on the web server. The debugger cannot connect to the remote computer in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684127/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-the-debugger-cannot-connect-to-the)

Comment: my host file is correct. it has the IP and the host name

Comment: See also : https://blog.nick.josevski.com/2015/02/17/iis-visual-studio-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server/

Comment: problem has been fixed!

Comment: if you fixed the problem and does not want to share the answer by leaving it below and accepting it, please do delete this question right now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was my host file was being saved in the wrong location.